# Is there a reason for the Community Bot to poke years-old questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

While browsing top questions on ux.SO home page (under Active tab), I was surprised to find some pretty old questions, from 2018, 2019 or so, apparently poked by the Community Bot:

[Is there a use case for overriding/overpainting the OS-provided system menu?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/120639/is-there-a-use-case-for-overriding-overpainting-the-os-provided-system-menu)

[What UX design patterns are suited for displaying a catalog online?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/129541/what-ux-design-patterns-are-suited-for-displaying-a-catalog-online)

[What navigation label would you give these list items?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/129309/what-navigation-label-would-you-give-these-list-items)

At first, I thought it is because to get people to answer them, but they already have answers (though not accepted by OPs). Or they are good 'general' questions, but this doesn't seem to be the case for the third one.

So, it is just that the Community Bot has a long time range, or there is a reason behind this?